# Make do with safety channel feature

Tags: audacity, multichannel, clipping, safety, how-to

I bought a mic that gives me original audio on the left channel, and -10db on the right channel (safety).

After recording my last session, it turns out that I do indeed have clipping happening on the left channel.

My question is, what is the process of actually restoring those clipped regions with the safety channel?

Are there tools that can just make it "work" automatically? Or will this need to be a tedious, manual process?

I have special interest in hearing about workflows using Audacity.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the non-clipping right channel. It will have sligthly more noise but no clipping compared to the left channel.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the stereo track which recorded both channels.
2. In the dropdown menu on the stereo track, choose "Split stereo track".
3. Delete the track containing the unwanted clipped audio.